# Save txt file as the name of a variable

Tags: c++

What I would like the user to do is type a file name in such as testquote and then for my program to add .txt to the end to save the file as a .txt, this is so I can save multiple quotes to the computer without over writing. This is what I have so far:

```
cout << "What would you like to save the quotation as? (Maybe using your last name) " << endl;
    cin >> nameOfFile;

    ofstream outfile; // Opens file in write mode
    outfile.open(nameOfFile)<<(".txt"); // Opens the quotations file
    //Lawn
    outfile << "The total lawn area is " << lawnArea << " square meters" << endl; // Writes users data into the file 
    outfile << "The total cost for the lawn is £" << (lawnArea * lawnCost) << endl; // Writes users data into the file
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Is `nameOfFile` a `std::string`?

Comment: `outfile.open(nameOfFile)<<(".txt"); // Opens the quotations file` No, it definitely doesn't!!! First construct the string (e.g. using `+` operator), then open the file with the constructed string.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `nameOfFile` is a `std::string`, you can use `std::string::operator+` to concatenate it with `".txt"`:

```
ofstream outfile(nameOfFile + ".txt");
```

(Note: there's no need to call `open` - just pass the filename to the constructor)

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect and thanks for the extra detail, many thanks! Will accept the answer when possible

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile.open(nameOfFile)<<(".txt"); // Opens the quotations file
```

This line of code is simply wrong. You seem to be confused with usage of the `operator<<` in conjunction with the `std::ofstream` class.

What you want is a `std::string` variable containing the name of the file to be opened. Appending a `.txt` extension should be done automatically, right?

So first have a variable to receive the users file name choice (without the `.txt`):

```
std::string nameOfFile;

// ...
cin >> nameOfFile;
```

Then append a `.txt`:

```
nameOfFile += ".txt";
```

Then construct a `std::ofstream` with this string:

```
std::ofstream outfile(nameOfFile.c_str());
```